# Compact set and finite definition

Tags: real-analysis

Hello this is my ipad so sorry for little poor quality of the question

1. Lets look At the sentence Open interval (0,1) is not compact.

Compact set definition is suppose to set should have finite subset of R to satisfy he compact definition

This E=(0.1) gives O=(0,1-1/n) , and its infinite cover does not include all E so it's not a compact set

But isn't it depend on which open cover u choose?

Like if u choose O=(0,n) it will cover with finite set

I think I'm missing some concept help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it depends on the choice of open cover. But look again at the definition of compactness: $E$ is compact if and only if **every** open cover of $E$ has a finite subcover. If there is even **one** open cover of $E$ that has no finite subcover, then $E$ is not compact, no matter how many open covers of $E$ there are that do have finite subcovers.

Comment: So since E has not finite set O such as (0,1-1/n), it does not satisfy the condition of compactness? Can you give one example of compact set with some open cover?  And why this compactness so important? Thank you

Comment: @sayuri: That’s correct: the open cover $$\left\{\left(0,1-\frac1n\right):n\ge 2\right\}$$ has no finite subcover, so $(0,1)$ is not compact.